# Need fix for TP-LINK TL-WN781ND 150Mbps Wireless PCI Express Network Nic

Tags: wireless

I have purchased a TP-LINK TL-WN781ND 150Mbps Wireless PCI Express Network Nic and running on Ubuntu latest version 14.04.2 I'm getting very slow speed.

Please see the required information about my network and devices [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10668995/).

But when I am using Mac and Windows systems I am getting good speed. Only problem when comes in the Ubuntu OS. And the wireless is showing very less range when connecting in Ubuntu OS (Showing hardly one bar out of 4 bars).

My router model: `Cisco Linksys E900` and is set in Network Mode: `Wireless-N only`

Upgrading the kernel gives: `linux-generic is already the newest version.`

The speed is better when using: `ethtool --change eth1 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off`

The speed doesn't improve beyond `ethtool --change eth1 speed 100 duplex half autoneg off`

Comment: Maybe try setting your router to legacy B/G mode? Wireless N is a little wacky. It might give stability to your connection, thus increasing the speed. BTW my Tplink 722N works great with Ubuntu and was cheap.

Comment: @Fabby Here is it. I have included the commands in it http://paste.ubuntu.com/10693284/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network card seems to be having an auto-negotiation issue or a cabling/port problem.

As the diagnostics in the comments don't improve the speed beyond 100MBit half duplex (50Mbps), please add the following commands to your `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
post-up ethtool --change eth1 speed 100 duplex half autoneg off
```

and that should provide a very stable workaround to your problem as these will survive a reboot whereas the `ethtool --change eth1 speed 100 duplex half autoneg off` just on the command-line does not.  So stable, in fact, that we can call it a "solution"...  ;-)

Comment: Performance has improved little bit. And I have ordered external high receiving power antenna to fix this :P Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Could you tell why I am not able to see the output for following commands..... ethtool -S eth1 and ethtool -a eth1

Comment: I don't use the short naming convention from the 1970s as they are hard to remember, so no, out of the top of my head I don't know...  However, if you [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this question and ask what you're trying to accomplish, I'd be happy to help!  **;-)  >:)**

Answer (score 0):

GOT the fix!!!

Since it was a signal issue I
 replaced my antenna 2dB to 10 dB.

Now im getting proper signal and great speed.

Thanks for the help guys on commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable wireless N, to get it to work reliably.

To do so, add:

```
options ath9k 11n_disable=1
```

to the file (create it, if it doesn't exist):

```
/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

You can do this with this command in the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

and add the line at the end. Restart your computer.