# Intel pro 5100 AGN wireless connection problem

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, hp, intel

Hello ladies and centlemen.
I recently grow an interest about Ubuntu OS. I was trying to use Lubuntu 3.16.0-31-generic(i686) on my old notebook HP Pavillon dv6. I succesfully manage to boot it. However, now i have a wierd wifi connection problem. It detects but doesn't connect my wi-fi at home, even though it connects my phone's wi-fi hot spot. It also can connect via cable. I searched all the forum and tried a few tricks but they didn't solve the issue. Here are some information;

**sudo lshw -numeric -C network:**

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection [8086:4237]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:22:fa:91:b7:ee
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-31-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:50 memory:de200000-de201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10EC:8168]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:23:8b:a8:c6:cb
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d4010000-d4010fff memory:d4000000-d400ffff memory:dd200000-dd20ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 02:56:64:37:35:37
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.158 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**lsmod :**

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection [8086:4237]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:22:fa:91:b7:ee
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-31-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:50 memory:de200000-de201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10EC:8168]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:23:8b:a8:c6:cb
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d4010000-d4010fff memory:d4000000-d400ffff memory:dd200000-dd20ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 02:56:64:37:35:37
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.158 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**rfkill list all :**

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**lspci :**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) Thermal Subsystem (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96M [GeForce 9600M GT] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Coa., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
06:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller
06:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller
06:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller
06:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller
06:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller
```

Do you have any idea why i cannot connect? Thank you.

Comment: Some intel wifi chipsets won't connect to a wireless N network unless a certain parameter is set `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disabled=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Comment: Hello Jeremy31. Thank you for your reply. I tried this parameter before but unfortunately it didn't worked. It still can detect and can't connect to wi-fi network. I tried Wicd and it always stucks at the "Validating authentication" phase.

Comment: Did you reboot after setting the parameter?

Comment: yes i did, still not working.

Comment: You might want to look at `iwlist scan` with your hotspot active and compare the results from your hotspot compared to your wifi access point to see if there are any differences in Group Cipher or Pairwise Cipher

Comment: My wifi access point Group Cipher: TKIP , Pairwise Cipher: TKIP CCMP.

But my phone's hotspot Group Cipher: CCMP , Pairwise Cipher: CCMP

Answer (score 0):

Change your wifi routers security settings to WPA2 only and reboot router and it should work better

Comment: i did but again it is still not working.

Comment: @jeremy31: Could you look at [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592567/need-fix-for-tp-link-tl-wn821n-wi-fi-adapter) for me and ping me in the chat room so I can delete this answer or leave a comment below...

Comment: @ Fabby, the other question is a problem with low signal strength which seems to be common in Linux.  And the TP-Link USB will never work when the modules are blacklisted